# "12:00" changed to "00:00" with Calendar object

Tags: android, calendar

I'm setting a Calendar object with

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");  

String datetime_str = "08-03-2013 12:00";

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(formatter.parse(datetime_str));
```

and I get this for my cal object:

```
 java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1362697200000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Amsterdam,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=10,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=8,DAY_OF_YEAR=67,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

the part I wasn't expecting being

```
HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0
```

Why is 12 (midday) changed to "00" (midnight)?

Comment: I can't be sure - not a java-coder - but in .NET the format for 24h hours is HH, not hh. If I do the same (equivalent of this) in C#, I get midnight as well. Changing to HH gives noon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HH` (0-23) or `kk` (1-24) for 24h-system. `hh` is for 1-12 (am/pm).

[Read about it in the SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)